# pandas converting numbers to corresponding elements of a list

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a series of numbers and a list:

```
s1 = pd.Series([0,1,2,5,4,1,0,2])
mylist = pd.Series(['apples','pears','bananas','oranges','lemons','limes'])
```

and I want to create a new series with values looked up using the list. If I do `mylist[s1]` the values are correct but the indices are wrong:

```
>>> mylist[s1]
0     apples
1      pears
2    bananas
5      limes
4     lemons
1      pears
0     apples
2    bananas
dtype: object
```

and I can do this to get the correct answer, but it seems cumbersome:

```
>>> pd.Series(mylist[s1].values, index=s1.index)
0     apples
1      pears
2    bananas
3      limes
4     lemons
5      pears
6     apples
7    bananas
dtype: object
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [177]: s1.map(mylist)
Out[177]: 
0     apples
1      pears
2    bananas
3      limes
4     lemons
5      pears
6     apples
7    bananas
dtype: object
```

`Series.map` is quite versatile -- not only does it accept sequences, it can also take a callable (like the Python built-in, `map`), or a Series or a dict.

Comment: awesome! I knew there would be something, couldn't find it for the life of me, though.